# Cannot reset a property in certain conditions, vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So, I have a 'mini-game' in Vue.js which let's you 'fight'.
I am trying to make it that after someone 'dies' the game declares the winner and then asks if you want to play again.
All good until there,but when i'm trying to make it so after you clicked that you want to play again, to reset your health and 'monster\'s' health back to 100, it just doesn't work. 
Here's my code, where i reset everything, it runs, i've put console logs but it does nothing:

```
checkWinner: function() {
    if(this.mHp <= 0) {
        if (confirm('You won! Play again?')) {
            this.startGame();
        } else {
            this.gameIsActive = false;
        }
        return true;
    } else if (this.pHp <= 0) {
        if (confirm('You lost! Play again?')) {
            this.startGame();
        } else {
            this.gameIsActive = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}
Also, here's the full code if you wanna take a look. I'd be thankful if someone could explain to me why it doesn't work. Thanks in advance !

http://jsfiddle.net/y5mn61qf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `startGame()` function, where your `pHp` and `mHp` variables are not being set with `this`.

You have:

```
pHp = 100;
mHp = 100;
```

Which should be:

```
this.pHp = 100;
this.mHp = 100;
```

I found this by using `console.log()` which helped me to determine that `startGame()` was firing, and then upon closer inspection led me to notice that your data was not being updated properly.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh I got it! Thanks! I was bashing my head. But, why do we have to set them with the this keyword, because we are in a method? for example, if i were to do it with v-on:click in the HTML page i wouldn't have to type this.

Comment: @TempAcct4Stack I know that within a template you don't need `this`, as I suppose the context has been defined. Within instance methods I believe the reason is to distinguish local variables from app data props. I'd double check the docs to be sure though :)

Answer (score 0):

In your startGame method you are setting the properties to a new value but forgot `this.` for the livespan values (pHp, mHp)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work after adding 'this' before your hp parameters.

```
    startGame: function() {
        this.gameIsActive = true;
        this.pHp = 100;
        this.mHp = 100;
    },
```